# What is the legal interpretation of "As satisfied by" in this passage?

Tags: legal-terms, regulations, interpretation

I had a difficulty understanding the meaning of "as satisfied" in the following sentence:

> references in these Regulations to any requirement for any document to be written, in writing, to be presented in writing or for the giving of any notice are to be construed as satisfied by a document or Record in electronic form (being a document or Record generated, communicated, received or stored by electronic, magnetic, optical or otherwise in an information system or for transmission from one information system to another) and any references in these Companies Regulations to any requirement for a signature on any document or notice are to be construed as satisfied by an Electronic Signature which may be proved in any manner;

Does it mean that in case a file is required in writing, then an electronic version is also acceptable in this case?

Comment: It might help to consider the larger phrase "are to be construed as satisfied by."  For more context, consider "references to *X* are to be construed as satisfied by *Y."*  This simply asserts that any mention of X includes Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an electronic version of the document is acceptable.

The excerpt you reproduce does not exclude paper filing. But other portion(s) of the contract or rules might clarify whether *only* electronic versions are acceptable or whether they may be an *alternative* to paper filing.